# Access the service layer from the controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, solr, spring-data

I am using a REST web service that queries data from Apache Solr. I'm using Spring boot + data with Solr repositories.
I do not know how to interconnect as service, repository, and controller layers.

[I have the following structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmEJX.png)

**Controller**:

```
@RestController
public class ImageSearchController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( this.getClass( ) ); 
    @Resource ImageService imageService;
....
}
```

**Main to SpringBootApplication**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class , args );
    }

}
```

**Service**:

```
public interface ImageService {

    List< Image > searchTerm( String searchTerm );
    List< Image > search(String imgSrc , String imgTitle);
    List< Image > searchByImgSrc( String searchTerm );
    List< Image > findAll( );   
}
```

**Service Impl**:

```
@Service
public class ImageServiceImpl implements ImageService {

    @Resource
    private ImageRepository repository;


    @Override
    public List< Image > search( String imgSrc , String imgTitle ) {
        return repository.findByImgSrcContainsOrImgTitleContains( imgSrc , imgTitle );
    }
....
}
```

**Repository (Spring Data)**:

```
public interface ImageRepository extends SolrCrudRepository< Image , String > {

    public List< Image > findAll( );

...
}
```

**Pom.xml**:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-solrj -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-solr -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
...

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

[Logs of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsoZi.png)

How to create the bean and access the controller in the service layer?
How to configure solr client with rest web service ?

**UPDATE**

I upgraded the spring boot version from 1.4.3 to 1.5.1 and it worked. Honestly, I do not understand why.
Now I get another error, when accessing solr, the spring data duplicates the name of the core in solr. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: edit: add pom file

Answer (score 1):

1st you don't need the service interface if you only have one implementation. 
You do not access the controller in the service layer it's the other way around. Controller > Service >Repository(solr in your case)
Controller defines your API, Service defines your business layer and repository you should be using to access external resources (solr in your case)

So in the Controller you `@Autowire` the service and in the serice you `@Autowire` the Repository

Comment: Yes, I got the idea. But I am not able to implement it .. Give me the error that I describe in the previous post. I do not know how to interconnect AppConfig with the controller and with the remaining layers.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should [inject your dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html). I recommend constructor injection. In your case:

```
@Service
public class ImageServiceImpl implements ImageService {

private final ImageRepository repository;

@Autowired // no necessary in spring 4.3+
public ImageServiceImpl(ImageRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, but I continue to receive the same exception: UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'imageSearchController' defined in file... 'imageServiceImpl' defined in file.. Error creating bean with name 'imageRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<?, ?>>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Try to annotate ImageRepository with @Repository

Answer (score 0):

The ImageRepository-Bean could not be found (Maybe you miss `@EnableJpaRepositories`) so spring is looking for a BeanFactory and finds a `SolrRepositoryFactoryBean` that requires a constructor-parameter of type (Class). Usually a Scanner of `@EnableJpaRepositories` constructs the `SolrRepositoryFactoryBean` but as long as `@EnableJpaRepositories` is missing (or configured wrong) the ImageRepository could not be constructed.

The Fix:

- Add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to the `Application` and configure the parameters of the annotation.